# lazy instantiation closures vs. just using methods

Tags: swift

I was following a Swift tutorial on closures and ran across this piece of code.

```
class HTMLEelement {
    let name: String
    let text: String

    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [weak self] in
        guard let this = self else { return "" }
        return "<\(this.name)> \(this.text) </\(this.name)>"
    }

    init(name:String, text: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        print("HTMLELEMENT \(name) is being deallocated")
    }
}
```

Why did they define the function `asHTML` like they did instead of just using a regular `public` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without declaring var as lazy, you cannot use "self" during its initialization. I think this was the main reason to use lazy in your example.

Comment: his point is why not to use a method instead of a lazy var , in a method he can also use self